# Rails/Mysql2/Lion [FATAL] failed to allocate memory

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, osx-lion

I seem to be getting this issue when trying to run a Rails 3.x site with POW using the mysql2 gem and on OSX Lion.

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

Also I am running Rails 2.x apps successfully with the same setup under POW.

I'm assuming this is an issue related to Lion + MySQL2 as other errors seem to indicate this to be the source but I can't seem to locate the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are a lot of issues with XCode 4.2 as far as I can tell. It could be caused by a clang-driven bug. If you have 4.2 installed you may want to try downloading 4.1 from Apple's website, uninstalling XCode 4.2, installing 4.1, and trying to reinstall all your gems...

Comment: I originally had 4.1 installed with the same issues, I then upgraded to 4.2 with similar issues.

Comment: Then maybe try to have GDB running the code (google's your friend), and see exactly where it breaks. You'll then be able to know whether it's mysql, ruby, ...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I used to `mysql-connector-c` & `mysql`. The problem was in `mysql-connector-c` which had old dylib. So problem resolved by removing `mysql-connector-c`, the next you have to change shell variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` or make symbol link for `libmysqlclient.18.dylib`. You should reinstall `mysql2` gem after this.

- To change `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` insert `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`  in your ~/.baschrc and reload shell
- To make symbol link for `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` evaluate in your shell this command:
  `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/`

I used here directory where my mysql installed. Change it to your's if you have another mysql location.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with node (installed using Homebrew) for me.

So I uninstalled and reinstalled node using Homebrew

first:

```
brew uninstall node
```

then:

```
brew install node
```